# Command which replaces all occurrences of a certain character with another character?

Tags: macros

How to define a command which replaces every instance of a certain character in its argument with another certain character?

For example, I'd like to define the command `\myreplace{1-2-abc-345}` which gives me the output `1.2.abc.345` by replacing every `-` with `.`.

Comment: If just normal text is involved in the argument (as opposed to macros), the `stringstrings` package might be of help.  There are other such packages, too.  I think `regex` is one, though I can't seem to locate it at the moment.

Comment: The `xstring` paskage has a `\StringSubstitute` command? But is it tobe used with chains of characters?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Use `expl3`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\myreplace}{m}
 {
  \tl_set:Nn \l__maxd_argument_tl { #1 }
  \tl_replace_all:Nnn \l__maxd_argument_tl { - } { . }
  \tl_use:N \l__maxd_argument_tl
 }
\tl_new:N \l__maxd_argument_tl
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\myreplace{1-2-abc-345}

\end{document}
```

[image]

What's the advantage? You can easily generalize your command using the same idea.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\myreplace}{ O{} m }
 {
  \maxd_replace:nn { #1 } { #2 }
 }

\tl_new:N \l__maxd_argument_tl
\cs_new_protected:Npn \maxd_replace:nn #1 #2
 {
  \group_begin:
  \tl_set:Nn \l__maxd_argument_tl { #2 }
  \keys_set:nn { maxd/replace } { #1 }
  \tl_replace_all:NVV \l__maxd_argument_tl \l_maxd_search_tl \l_maxd_replace_tl
  \tl_use:N \l__maxd_argument_tl
  \group_end:
 }
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \tl_replace_all:Nnn { NVV }

\keys_define:nn { maxd/replace }
 {
  search .tl_set:N = \l_maxd_search_tl,
  search .initial:n = { - },
  replace .tl_set:N = \l_maxd_replace_tl,
  replace .initial:n = { . }
 }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\myreplace{1-2-abc-345}

\myreplace[replace=--]{1-2-abc-345}

\myreplace[search=2,replace=0]{1-2-abc-345}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 12):

One way would be to use `\StrSubstitute` from [the `xstring` package](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/xstring):

[image]

### Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xstring}

\newcommand{\myreplace}[2]{%
    \StrSubstitute{#2}{-}{.}[#1]%
}%

\begin{document}
\myreplace{\NewValue}{1-2-abc-345}
input: 1-2-abc-345 

output: \NewValue

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 11):

Another solution using only TeX primitives:

```
\def\addto#1#2{\expandafter\def\expandafter#1\expandafter{#1#2}}
\def\replacestrings#1#2{%
   \def\tmp##1#1##2\end{\ifx\end##2\end\addto\tmpb{##1}\else\addto\tmpb{##1#2}\tmp##2\end\fi}%
   \expandafter\def\expandafter\tmpb\expandafter{\expandafter}\expandafter\tmp\tmpb#1\end 
}
\def\myreplace#1{\def\tmpb{#1}\replacestrings{-}{.}\tmpb}

\myreplace{1-2-abc-345}
```

**Edit:** I'll try to explain *how it works*. IMHO, it is more valuable to know how TeX works inside than only usage the code or package without thinking.

First line defines `\addto<macro>{<text>}` which adds to the `<macro>` the `<text>`. For example after `\def\a{xx} \addto\a{yy}` we have `\a` defined as `xxyy`.

The `\replacestrings{<string1>}{<string2>}` replaces all occurrences of `<string1>` in the `\tmpb` macro to the `<string2>`. First, the `\tmp` macro is defined at line 3 as:

```
\def\tmp#1<string1>#2\end{...}
```

Second, the `\tmp` is executed with expanded `\tmpb` as a parameter followed by `\end`. The `\tmpb` is (1) expanded, (2) it is set to empty and (3) the `\tmp` is executed. This is the reason of 5x `\expandafter` in line 4.

Suppose, we have `\def\tmpb{abXXcdXXef}` and we run `\replacestring{XX}{YY}`. Then `\tmp` is declared as the following pseudocode:

```
\def\tmp#1XX#2\end{if #2 is empty: \addto\tmpb{#1}
                   else: \addto\tmpb{#1YY}
                         \tmp #2\end
                   fi}
```

Then `\tmp aaXXcdXXefXX\end` is executed, but the `\tmpb` is set to empty first.
The `\tmp` expands with `#1=aa`, `#2=cdXXefXX`. Because `#2` isn't empty, the

```
\addto\tmpb{aaYY} \tmp cdXXefXX\end
```

is executed. So, `\tmpb` includes `aaYY`. The second run of `\tmp` expands with `#1=cd` `#2=efXX` to

```
\addto\tmpb{cdYY} \tmp efXX\end
```

Now, `\tmpb` includes `aaYYcdYY`. The third run of `\tmp` expands with `#1=ef` and `#2` empty to

```
\addto\tmpb{ef}
```

This gives the result in `\tmpb` `aaYYcdYYef`.

An attentive reader can give notice that there is a bug: if the replaced text ends with one `X`, for example `\def\tmpb{aaXXbbX}` and `<string1>` is `XX` then there is a problem. It is true, but the question in this thread demands to replace only one token to one token. The real `\replacestrings` (used in OPmac, for example) does one more step: adds the special token at the end of the replaced text, then does the replacement and then removes this special token.

Answer (score 7):

Another solution using the `stringstrings` package as suggested by [Steven B. Segletes](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/25858/steven-b-segletes):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{stringstrings}

\newcommand{\myreplace}[1]{\convertchar{#1}{-}{.}}

\begin{document}

\myreplace{1-2-abc-345} %output: 1.2.abc.345

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

> I'd like to define the command `\myreplace{1-2-abc-345}` which gives me the output `1.2.abc.345` by replacing every `-` with `.`

Here's a LuaLaTeX-based solution, which uses Lua's powerful `gsub` string function.

[image]

```
% !TEX TS-program = lualatex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{luacode}
\begin{luacode}
function myreplace ( s ) 
   return ( unicode.utf8.gsub ( s , "-", "." ) )
end
\end{luacode}
\newcommand\myreplace[1]{\directlua{myreplace(\luastringN{#1})}}

\begin{document}
\myreplace{1-2-abc-345}
\end{document}
```