# How to replace a certain word(s) in Latex

Tags: templates

This is my first work on Latex and I have problem - I downloaded a template from

[Latex Template](http://www.sunilpatel.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2010/08/Thesis-Template.zip)

which is a very nice template. However, until I go to page 4th (Abstract). I cannot replace Doctor of Philosophy with something else. I searched though the main file `Thesis.tex` and `Thesis.cls` but no hope. I guess it belongs to some kind of linked file.

I tried something like this [possible solution](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/185682/command-which-replaces-a-certain-character-of-its-argument) but it does not work. I am using TeXstudio with MiKTeX 2.9

[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Did you really search `Thesis.cls`? Take a look at line 247 in that file.

Comment: Line 204 might also be of interest.

Comment: @Oh - I searched for the word Doctor but I did not find and I just looked at the Abstract on the main `thesis.tex` and did not find anything special. Thanks Both.

Comment: I take a look again, I detected what happend - even I active the tab `thesis.cls`, when I searched, it actual searched the words in `thesis.tex` that why it resulted "End of scope reached with no match. Restart from Beginning?"

Comment: Use Ctrl R to replace words or equations or whatever

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The simplest way for modifying the phrase is to add a couple of lines to the `.tex` document.

I'll take the example document as a basis, you find the change between self-explaining comments:

```
%% ----------------------------------------------------------------
%% Thesis.tex -- MAIN FILE (the one that you compile with LaTeX)
%% ---------------------------------------------------------------- 

% Set up the document
\documentclass[a4paper, 11pt, oneside]{Thesis}  % Use the "Thesis" style, based on the ECS Thesis style by Steve Gunn
\graphicspath{{Figures/}}  % Location of the graphics files (set up for graphics to be in PDF format)

% Include any extra LaTeX packages required
\usepackage[square, numbers, comma, sort&compress]{natbib}  % Use the "Natbib" style for the references in the Bibliography
\usepackage{verbatim}  % Needed for the "comment" environment to make LaTeX comments
\usepackage{vector}  % Allows "\bvec{}" and "\buvec{}" for "blackboard" style bold vectors in maths
\hypersetup{urlcolor=blue, colorlinks=true}  % Colours hyperlinks in blue, but this can be distracting if there are many links.

%%%% We want to change the phrase `Doctor of Philosophy' in the abstract
%%%% Replace `Anything I want' with the phrase you want (even with nothing)
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\patchcmd{\abstract}{Doctor of Philosophy}{Anything I want}{}{}
%%%% End of change

%% ----------------------------------------------------------------
\begin{document}
```

No other change is needed.

A problem with these templates is that they use the `vmargin` package, which may cause issues with other packages, notably `pdfpages`. Another problem is the choice of colors.

[image]

Comment: thank you very much - this will be very good that I may need to replace more words in the future as I will start my thesis in this Fall. My advisor just told me I should learn some Latex by before the term begins.

Comment: @user7726 A good adviser. The contrary is put the cart before thehorse (and a huge waste of time).