# Replacing characters in the argument - even within other commands

Tags: expansion, expl3, strings

I need to replace all characters given as argument with other characters, doing some sort of transliteration.

[This answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/185693/6819) provides a solution that works nicely with XeLaTeX and Unicode. Unfortunately it cannot replace within arguments of commands that occur within the `\myreplace`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\myreplace}{m}
 {
  \tl_set:Nn \l__maxd_argument_tl { #1 }
  \tl_replace_all:Nnn \l__maxd_argument_tl { e } { ẹ }
  \tl_replace_all:Nnn \l__maxd_argument_tl { E } { Ẹ }
  \tl_use:N \l__maxd_argument_tl
 }
\tl_new:N \l__maxd_argument_tl
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\myreplace{Ee} \myreplace{E\emph{e}}

\end{document}
```

A general solution for all text-commands would be fantastic, but solving it for `\emph` only would be fine for my purpose.

I'd also be interested to learn whether I could add some basic error-handling, e.g. by making the macro replace all characters other than the specified ones by something that's spotted easily, like "???".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`regex_replace_all:nnN` does work here:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\myreplace}{m}
 {
  \tl_set:Nn \l__maxd_argument_tl { #1 }
  \regex_replace_all:nnN { e } { x } \l__maxd_argument_tl
  \regex_replace_all:nnN { E } { X } \l__maxd_argument_tl
  \tl_use:N \l__maxd_argument_tl
 }
\tl_new:N \l__maxd_argument_tl
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\myreplace{Ee} \myreplace{E\emph{e}}

\end{document}
```

To make it work for your special characters with pdfLaTeX one has to specify the correct category codes for the replacement (don't use this with LuaLaTeX or XeLaTeX -- it will throw an error):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\myreplace}{m}
 {
  \tl_set:Nn \l__maxd_argument_tl { #1 }
  \regex_replace_all:nnN { e } { \cA(ẹ) } \l__maxd_argument_tl
  \regex_replace_all:nnN { E } { \cA(Ẹ) } \l__maxd_argument_tl
  \tl_use:N \l__maxd_argument_tl
 }
\tl_new:N \l__maxd_argument_tl
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\myreplace{Ee} \myreplace{E\emph{e}}

\end{document}
```

Comment: @Mico I thought OP was using XeLaTeX?! I just replaced it with x and X because my vim has a binding to `pdflatex` and none to `xelatex`. Your answer doesn't work with pdflatex, too :P

Comment: @Mico see my edit for pdflatex compatibility.

Answer (score 5):

Here's a LuaLaTeX-based solution. It can handle utf8-encoded characters in the text substitution operation, and it can handle all embedded macro names, including `\emph`. (The only assumption is that argument of `\myreplace`  contains no macros whose names contain the characters `ẹ` or `Ẹ` to begin with. This shouldn't be a binding restriction, right?)

[image]

```
% !TEX TS-program = lualatex
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{luacode}
\begin{luacode*}
```

```lua
function myreplace ( s )
  s = unicode.utf8.gsub ( s, "E", "Ẹ" )
  s = unicode.utf8.gsub ( s, "e", "ẹ" )
  s = unicode.utf8.gsub ( s , "\\[%aẸẹ]+" , 
        function ( x )
           x = unicode.utf8.gsub ( x , "ẹ" , "e" )
           x = unicode.utf8.gsub ( x , "Ẹ" , "E" )
           return ( x )
        end )
  tex.sprint ( s )
end
```

```tex
\end{luacode*}
\newcommand\myreplace[1]{\directlua{myreplace(\luastringN{#1})}}

\begin{document}
\myreplace{Ee} \myreplace{E\textit{e}\emph{e}\textbf{E}}
\end{document}
```