# New command and catcode

Tags: expansion, catcodes, definition

I have a command that may contain the ampersand charater: `&`. Sometimes, when I use this command, I want that ampersand interpreted as a space. This is why I wanted to use the TeX command `\catcode`.

While the code below seems to be OK

```latex
\catcode`\&=11
\ensuremath{2&=2}
\catcode`\&=4
```

When I put the content inside a definition with `\def` for example:

```latex
  \def\foobar{\ensuremath{2&=2}}
  \catcode`\&=11
  \foobar
  \catcode`\&=4
```

I get an error message:

```
Misplaced alignment tab character &.
leading text:   \foobar
```

How can I solve my problem? Moreover, I don't understand why the second snippet generates this error message while the first one does not.

Comment: The catcode of the character has to be set when the `\def` is being executed, not when it defined command is being expanded. More precisely, the catcode is set when TeX first sees the character. You'd have to use ``\catcode`\&=11 \def\foobar{\ensuremath{2&=2}} \catcode`\&=4``. Furthermore, the catcode of a space is 10, not 11.

Comment: I used 11 for my tests. Ok, I mixed parsing and execution. Thanks.

Comment: Is there a way to achieve my goal dynamically though? Replacing the token generated by `&` by the token corresponding to a space?

Comment: Sorry, I didn't understand what exactly you want to achieve. If you want to force a space in math mode you can use `\def\foobar{\ensuremath{2\ =2}}`... Or, if you want a proper space token you can use `\@sptoken`.

Comment: `\ensuremath{2&=2}` looks a very odd construct, why the `\ensuremath` ? if it is in math the `\ensuremath` does nothing, and if it is not in math then it is `$2&=2$` which would be an error if `&` has its normal catcode.

Comment: I probably oversimplified my example. Originally, the math code is something contained in an align environment. Here, I used the ampersand just for the snippet.
Then my point is to define a command `\def\foo[1]{#1 ... #1}` such that the first occurrence of the argument is normal and the second one is the one where ampersands are replaced by spaces.

Comment: I finally solved my problem using this thread https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/185682/command-which-replaces-all-occurrences-of-a-certain-character-with-another-chara