# How to use \catcode in a command?

Tags: macros, catcodes

I would like to define the character `@` as follows:

`` \def @#1#2{\catcode`#1=13\def #1{#2}} ``

so that when I type `@xy x`, TeX typesets `y`. However, when I run this, I get an error.

I have seen other answers [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/12638/how-to-change-the-catcode-in-a-macro) and [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/476632/new-command-and-catcode) that ask about changing catcodes in commands. However, none of the answers given solve the problem in a way that I would like -- they simply move the `\catcode` out of the macro. There is also the solution

```
\catcode`@=13
\def @#1{\catcode`#1=13\def}
@xx{y} x
```

which yields the same result `y`. However, for my own purposes, I would like to achieve the above goal in the least amount of characters (3): `@xy`. I attempted to use `\expandafter`, to no avail. Is this possible?

Comment: With `\def@#1#2{...}` and `@xy x`, when `@` absorbs `x` as its first argument, the catcode of `x` is still letter, not active. Then TeX complains at `\def x{y}`.

Comment: Do you wish to use `@` for redefining active curly opening brace or active curly closing brace or active hash or active space as well? (If so you need some trickery for stringifying subsequent tokens and cranking out a space...)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You must to use `\lowercase` trick:

```
\def @#1#2{\catcode`#1=13 \bgroup \lccode`\~=`#1\lowercase{\egroup \def~}{#2}}

% test:
@ABA
```

The `~` is active by default in all formats and `\lowercase` changes the active `~` to an active character what you want.

Comment: There's a longer explanation at [TeX macro idioms, or: understanding advanced macros - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/86143/tex-macro-idioms-or-understanding-advanced-macros/86147#86147) .

Answer (score 6):

wipet's answer is the way to get the syntax you suggest but if you change to use a doubled character, so `@xxy   ... x` then you can avoid issues with accessing the character being defined before it is active, so use a simpler definition. This is the scheme used in [`xii.tex`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/xii) which uses `A` rather than `@` but for example `AZZFLaLP` is equivalent to your suggested  `@Z{LaL}` but with `Z` that is being defined doubled. `@ZZ{LaL}`

```
\let~\catcode~`76~`A13~`F1~`j00~`P2jdefA71F~`7113jdefPALLF
PA''FwPA;;FPAZZFLaLPA//71F71iPAHHFLPAzzFenPASSFthP;A$$FevP
A@@FfPARR717273F737271P;ADDFRgniPAWW71FPATTFvePA**FstRsamP
AGGFRruoPAqq71.72.F717271PAYY7172F727171PA??Fi*LmPA&&71jfi
Fjfi71PAVVFjbigskipRPWGAUU71727374 75,76Fjpar71727375Djifx
:76jelse&U76jfiPLAKK7172F71l7271PAXX71FVLnOSeL71SLRyadR@oL
RrhC?yLRurtKFeLPFovPgaTLtReRomL;PABB71 72,73:Fjif.73.jelse
B73:jfiXF71PU71 72,73:PWs;AMM71F71diPAJJFRdriPAQQFRsreLPAI
I71Fo71dPA!!FRgiePBt'el@ lTLqdrYmu.Q.,Ke;vz vzLqpip.Q.,tz;
;Lql.IrsZ.eap,qn.i. i.eLlMaesLdRcna,;!;h htLqm.MRasZ.ilk,%
s$;z zLqs'.ansZ.Ymi,/sx ;LYegseZRyal,@i;@ TLRlogdLrDsW,@;G
LcYlaDLbJsW,SWXJW ree @rzchLhzsW,;WERcesInW qt.'oL.Rtrul;e
doTsW,Wk;Rri@stW aHAHHFndZPpqar.tridgeLinZpe.LtYer.W,:jbye
```

Or, if you prefer `\`  as escape character rather than `j`

```
\catcode`\@13
\def\dodef#1#2{\def#1{#2}}
\def@#1{\catcode`#1=13 \dodef}

@xxy   abc x

@ww{hello}  hmmm what

\bye
```

[image]

`\dodef`here is just so the braces are optional and you can use `@xxy` instead of `@xx{y}`. The `xii` version uses `\def` directly so you would need `@xx{y}` but you can use arguments so that for example `@xx#1{(#1)}  xq` would expand to `(q)`

Comment: Hey!  I was half expecting Krampus to emerge!

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes be good or it may emerge when you least expect

Answer (score 4):

The code you show assumes that `@` is active to begin with, so a declaration `` \catcode`@=\active `` is needed somewhere.

What happens with your

```
\def @#1#2{\catcode`#1=13\def #1{#2}}
@xy x
```

attempt? That TeX complains about a missing control sequence, because there is *no* control sequence or active character in the replacement text of `@` and `x` is tokenized  with its category code *before* the `\catcode` assignment is performed.

You can use the `\lowercase` trick as shown by wipet, or a different approach with `expl3` (that can be used with plain TeX, but only with e-TeX extensions on).

```
\input expl3-generic

\ExplSyntaxOn

% first a generic function
\cs_new_protected:Nn \bshepard_catcode_def:nnn
 {% #1 = character to be made active
  % #2 = argument list, may be empty
  % #3 = replacement text
  \cs_new:cn { __bshepard_catcode_def_#1:#2 } { #3 }
  \char_set_active_eq:nc { `#1 } { __bshepard_catcode_def_#1:#2 }
  \char_set_catcode_active:n { `#1 }
 }

%initialize @
\bshepard_catcode_def:nnn { @ } { nn } { \bshepard_catcode_def:nnn { #1 } { } { #2 } }

\ExplSyntaxOff

@xy x

\show x

\bye
```

The console will show

```
> x=\long macro:
->y.
l.22 \show x
```

What's happening? The generic function takes three arguments: a character to be made active, the specification for the arguments its active value will look for and the replacement text.

This will define an internal function based on the character and set the active character meaning equivalent to this internal function, then activates the character.

The line

```
\bshepard_catcode_def:nnn { @ } { nn } { \bshepard_catcode_def:nnn { #1 } { } { #2 } }
```

activates `@` and tell TeX that its meaning is to look for two arguments (the first of which must be a character) and applies the generic function to this character.